# can i remove JAXB-api.jar from lib folder, when we are using JDK1.6 or above

Tags: java, xml, jar, jaxb

In our application in lib folder we have jaxb-api.jar which was there from so many years when we are using jdk1.5 and all.
but now, we have upgraded to jdk1.8 and still I find the jaxb-api.jar in our lib path.

I thought the jar will be included in jdk1.6 and above, so can I remove the jar from the lib? or will the JVM takes the jar from the folder?
I am very much new to this topic so can please help me in this?

Answer (score 0):

Just move that jar from lib to another location for testing purposes and start app. If everything start then yes you can remove it else check the error and try to read docs maybe you need to upgrade something to migrate to new version.

**JAXB** is part of jdk since  [JDK1.6](https://jaxb.java.net/guide/Which_JAXB_RI_is_included_in_which_JDK_.html).

for more information take a look to [Introduction to JAXB](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/intro/index.html)